# Не могу реализовать функцию, которая определяет, когда элемент виден в окне браузера

Tags: javascript

Нашел данную функцию в одном примере. У меня она не работает, не могу понять причины. Может кто-нибудь знает, в чем проблема? Буду признателен.

```
 function isElementInViewport(el) {
  const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
    rect.top >= 0 &&
    rect.left >= 0 &&
    rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && 
    rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
  );
}

function autoAnimation(){
        const buttom = document.querySelector(".pipe");
        if(isElementInViewport(buttom)){
            alert("get!");
        }
    }
```

Сам элемент ".pipe"

```
<div class="conection__block">
            <div class="pipe" type="button" onclick="startAnimation(this)" id="fitingOne">
                <div class="pipe__pointer"></div>
                <h3 class="pipe__title">приварка стальных фитингов: </h3>
                <p class="pipe__text">отводы; тройники; переходы; заглушки;</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: [intersection observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) может без лишней боли тут выручить. В конкретном примере сейчас не могу зазбираться, но апишку советую почитать. Там не сложно.

Comment: В приведенных функциях нет ошибки. Должно быть, ошибка в том - где и как они вызываются.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема найдена.
Функция вызывалась через addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"), когда надо было через scroll.

Всем спасибо за помощь!